# Unblock an automated blocked user

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I used [Login Security](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_security) module to block users after some login failures. It works fine however I need to unblock such users after certain time like after 1 hour/day. How would I do that as it has configurations to *delete attempt* from database but user isn't unblocked and it has to be *active* manually.

Please see below attached screen shot of module configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small module named as [Auto Unblock Users](https://www.drupal.org/project/auu) to unblock users.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following modules for managing blocked users. These help you in unblocking the user via admin UI. The modules are flood_control and flood_unblock

Url's to download the modules are https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_control https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_unblock

Comment: Via admin UI, its in core we can unblock users manually. As I asked automatically after some time in my question so your suggestion isn't worked for me.